# How to display data with reactJs?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, chat

I am using ReactJs with Laravel as an API. I Want to display some data but nothing worked for me.

This is the result of the API:

```js
{
    "user_id": 2,
    "id": 1,
    "chat": [
        {
            "sender_id": 3,
            "message": "Hi"
        },
        {
            "sender_id": 4,
            "message": "Hello"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to display `user_id`, it displayed it but the other part, the chat, didn't show up.

This is how I consume the API:

```js
const [chatsData, setChats] = useState([]);

// ** Renders Chat
useEffect(() => {
  getChats()
}, []);

const getChats = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}/api/listChats`);
  setChats(response.data);
}

<ul className='chat-users-list chat-list media-list'>
  {chatsData.map((item) => {
    return (
      <>
        <Avatar img={item?.senders?.user_image} imgHeight='42' imgWidth='42' />

        <li><h5>{item.chat?.message}</h5></li>
      </>
    )
  })}
</ul>
```

I will be very thankful if anyone could help me.

Comment: what do you means by recursively in that case ?

Comment: I didn't meant it I juste want to display the msg and the sender name @YassineCHABLI

Comment: `chatData` holds the complete data object. `chatsData.chat` holds the array of chat messages and sender ids. so you need to loop through chatsData.chat I would assume. and this line `{item.chat?.message}` wouldnt work since item.chat will be an array. Also assuming `chatData` is an array since you didnt report any error in chatData.map.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to loop on the chat field like:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const response = {
    user_id: 2,
    id: 1,
    chat: [
      {
        sender_id: 3,
        message: 'Hi',
      },
      {
        sender_id: 4,
        message: 'Hello',
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="chat-users-list chat-list media-list">
        {response.chat?.map((item) => {
          return (
            <>
              <li>
                <h5>
                  {item.sender_id} :  {item?.message}
                </h5>
              </li>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code example [here](https://react-ucfr4e.stackblitz.io)

Comment: @yassinechalbi my data is stored on database. when I try ` {chatsData?.chat?.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <>
                  <Avatar img={item?.senders?.user_image} imgHeight='42' imgWidth='42' />

                  <li><h5>{item.sender_id}</h5></li>
                  </>
                )
              } `  I didn't get anything

Comment: do you get the response from the server correctly ?

Comment: @yassinechalbi (2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {user_id: 2, id: 1, chat: Array(2)}
1: {user_id: 2, id: 2, chat: Array(2)}
length: 2  ..this is the data in the console

Comment: @stackuser if I may insert, chatsData is an array so as an experiment try this: `chatsData[0]?.chat?.map`. That should give you the chat messages in the first element of the chatsData array.

Comment: @user3532758 I get the data

Comment: @stackuser does this mean you've already solved your problem?